# How do I reverse engineer code in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have Enterprise Architect and created a Class Model, which exported beautifully into PHP code. Suring the coding phase a small set of changes were made to the structure and I want to reverse engineer my code back into the Class Model in Enterprise Architect. My code is up to date in teh same location I exported to, but I can't figure out how to update my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is linked to the model, you can use the Project->Source Code Engineering->Synchronize Package Contents (Ctrl+Alt+M), then "Reverse engineer (source->model)" option.

Enterprise Architect uses the directory names specified when the project source was first imported/generated and updates either the model or the source code depending on the option chosen.